# Byte Buddy 1.11.1 has problem with Android

Tags: byte-buddy

I am using Byte Buddy in Android and I switched from version 1.10.17 to 1.11.1 but I noticed the new version has problems and is giving me the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to resolve the class file version of the current VM: This JVM's version string does not seem to be valid: 0
    at net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion$VersionLocator$Unresolved.resolve(ClassFileVersion.java:558)
    at net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion.ofThisVm(ClassFileVersion.java:276)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterList$ForLoadedExecutable.of(ParameterList.java:205)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$ForLoadedMethod.getParameters(MethodDescription.java:1179)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder.compile(TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder.java:82)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation$ImplementationDelegate$ForStaticMethod.of(MethodDelegation.java:948)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation$WithCustomProperties.to(MethodDelegation.java:1512)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation$WithCustomProperties.to(MethodDelegation.java:1493)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation.to(MethodDelegation.java:271)
... 34 more
```

any idea why this is and what can I do ?

Comment: It seems like Byte Buddy cannot parse your version string. Could you check what System.getProperty("java.version") returns on that VM?

Comment: I am using a emulated android device and System.getProperty("java.version") returns "0". I also tested with my phone and it also gave "0". maybe in Android System.getProperty("java.version") just returns "0"

Comment: yes I checked android documentation and it says in Android "java.version" property does always return 0.

Comment: Darn, Android. I probably removed a safe-hook that allowed this value before. I will change this and release a patch release in the next days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fixed on the master branch of Byte Buddy and will be solved with version 1.11.2. The issue is indeed that Android issues version number *0* which is not correctly processed.